# Creating a "Goal" Tracker for an existing project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a current MVC project that is near enough complete for the basic aspects. The project tracks my progress throughout my running and weight loss as I find a lot of apps out there a bit bloated.

I have some basic models:

Distance:

```
public class Distance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Distance Run")]
    public double DistanceRun { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Choose a date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Any Addtional Comments")]
    public String AdditionalComments { get; set; }
}
```

Weight:

```
 {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Current Weight")]
    public double CurrentWeight { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Chose a date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Any Addtional Comments")]
    public String AdditionalComments { get; set; }
}
```

how would I go about creating a type of Goal creator for each one of these models. When I mean goal I mean "x amount run by y date"

I would try a possible Goal Model that would have fields similar to:

Goal:

```
public class Goal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual double goalValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }

}
```

My issue lies where to differentiate whether the goal is either for DIstance run or Weight Lost/Gained. Am I on the right lines or should I reconsider and not use a model?

Comment: You are doing it right . it doesnt matter if its weight or distance cos madel is just a container to store values for a time being so go with the current notation don't need to specify weight or distance here

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using inheritance. Create a base class like:

```
public class Metric
{
    [DisplayName("Chose a date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Any Addtional Comments")]
    public String AdditionalComments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, have both `Distance` and `Weight` inherit from this:

```
public class Distance : Metric
{
}

public class Weight : Metric
{
}
```

Then, your `Goal` can have a foreign key to `Metric`:

```
public class Goal
{
   ...
   public virtual Metric Metric { get; set; }
}
```

Based on how Entity Framework handles inheritance, it will actually instantiate `Distance`/`Weight` depending on which one was actually saved. The property value will be upcasted to `Metric`, though, so you'll need to cast to access the properties on your derived classes:

```
if (goal.Metric is Distance)
{
    var distanceRun = ((Distance)goal.Metric).DistanceRun;
}
```

You can also simply use `as` and then check for null:

```
var distance = goal.Metric as Distance;
if (distance != null)
{
    // do something with `distance`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ID to a reference table that differentiates the different types is a solution to the problem.  I think from an MVC-side, inheritance isn't going to work because on postback, the framework won't know what type of object to create (Distance or Weight for instance).  So while inheritance may work as @Chris suggested, on the MVC side you need a composite object with some identifying value to determine which type of object is.  That's where a reference table can come in handy.

OR, create a view model for the MVC side, and not load and save raw EF objects directly.  Doing that adds work, but can ensure the UI design doesn't entangle the database design.